# How can I echo multiple json source file into one loop?

Tags: php, json

I would like to echo datas from multiple json file, but only one json file works correctly. Please help me for multiple json file. THX

```
<?php

$water = file_get_contents('https://example.com/plant.json');
$wall = file_get_contents('https://example.com/door.json'); // How?

$decode = json_decode($water);
$data = $decode->data;

foreach ($data as $datas) {
    echo '<div>' . $datas->ice . '</div>';
    echo '<div>' . $datas->desk . '</div>';
}

/*

Content of plant.json file:
{"data":[
    {"ice":eight,"desk":"six"},
    {"ice":"ten","desk":"cup"}
]}

Content of door.json file:
{"data":[
    {"ice":pen,"desk":"sing"},
    {"ice":"bear","desk":"wire"}
]}

*/

?>
```

Comment: Am I missing something or did you forget to `json_decode` the `$wall` ? You'll need to combine the `data` from `$water` and `$wall` if you want it done in one `foreach` but I feel like the time spent doing that optimization may be wasted.

Comment: I just made only one line for `$wall`. I was not sure in the rest.

Comment: So how do you want to make use of the wall data in your output

Comment: Same as like water.

Comment: A quick painless solution would be to just `$decode = json_decode($wall);
$data = $decode->data;` and rerun your foreach loop ?

Comment: Yes, loop with wall.